# Why didn't Athos/Comte de la Fère kill Milady when he conversed with her?

Tags: alexandre-dumas-pere, the-three-musketeers

When they were married, Milady Clarik/Anne de Breuil have not yet committed any major crimes, but Comte de la Fère had no problem killing her (Yay for French Aristocracy!).

> “Truth, my friend. The angel was a demon; the poor young girl had stolen the sacred vessels from a church.”
> ...  “... He tore the dress of the countess to pieces; he tied her hands behind her, and hanged her on a tree.” (*"Chapter XXV. PORTHOS"*)

Yet, when they meet and converse at the at the inn of the Red Dovecot where Richeleu told Milady to kill Buckingham (*"Chapter XLV.
A CONJUGAL SCENE"*):

- Athos recites to Milady ALL the crimes she already committed
- Miledy threatens to kill D'Artagnan and Constance
- And yet, he's merely ***tempted*** to kill her, but yet for some reason doesn't and merely threatens her with death to get the signed absolution letter from the Cardinal

> The sight of this creature, who had nothing of the woman about her, recalled awful remembrances. He thought how one day, **in a less dangerous situation** than the one in which he was now placed, **he had already endeavored to sacrifice her to his honor**

Why didn't he just kill her then and there? He wouldn't be under suspicion as nobody knew he was at the house (even the other 3 Musketeers, whom he told at the bastion later); AND he could have taken Cardinal's letter from her.

## So why did he decide to wait till she killed Constance to get rid of Milady?

He says:

> “And now,” said Athos, resuming his cloak and putting on his hat, “now that I have drawn your teeth, viper, bite if you can.”

... but she already committed all sorts of crimes before she had the "get out of jail" letter from the Cardinal.

P.S. Upon reading further in the next chapter (*"Chapter XLVII.
THE COUNCIL OF THE MUSKETEERS"*):

1. I'm not the only one to ask this question, it seems:

   > “But when you held her in your power, why did you not drown her, strangle her, hang her?” said Porthos. “It is only the dead who do not return.”

   **Athos never answers this question :(**  (his response merely refers to the fact that she survived his first attempt as rebuke to Porthos' last assertion).

   > “You think so, Porthos?” replied the Musketeer, with a sad smile which D’Artagnan alone understood.
2. And yet, when they discuss killing her, Athos' "master stroke" idea is to merely end up with her in detention (by writing to her BIL, Lord De Winter); and explicitly tells D'Artagnan he's out of ideas:

   > “Ah, my faith!” said Athos, “you require too much, D’Artagnan. I have given you all I have, and I beg leave to tell you that this is the bottom of my sack.”